# Transfer contract's value from one to another

Tags: solidity

I have a contract `CampaignFactory` below that creates instances of the contract `Campaign` using the function `createCampaign`. This function is marked as *payable*.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.16 <0.9.0;
contract CampaignFactory {
    Campaign[] public deployedCampaigns;
    
    function createCampaign(uint minimum) public payable {
        Campaign newCampaign = new Campaign(minimum, msg.sender);
        deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);
    }
}
```

Now, what I need to do is if a user calls the `createCampaign` function, I need to transfer all those ethers sent in by the user to the created campaign contract. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this work:

```
function createCampaign(uint minimum) public payable {
            uint256 amount = msg.value;
    
            Campaign newCampaign = new Campaign(minimum, msg.sender);
            deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);
            newCampaign.transfer(amount);
        }
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not seem to work for me.

Comment: as I remember the contract should be configured to accept funds on it account without calling contract method, maybe this is the issue

Comment: Another idea not related to the question - why create a contract ? Because is most expensive in terms of the gas process, maybe the better way is issue the ERC721 token that is standard but could have a lot of features as agreement between the owner and user (sender) there is example of it from my project https://github.com/REGA-RS/ERC721SmartToken

Comment: Thank you. I will check. +1 for the ERC suggestion.